# Maximize tree height while minimizing children count of any node?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, tree

I am currently faced with the following problem:

Given is a tree with an unchangeable root node and n children.
I need to optimize this tree so that:

1. The children count of any node is minimized (only talking about the direct children of a node here, not their children or the like)
2. As a result of this, the tree height is maximized
3. The tree is descending in order, so that always node > child

All nodes are < root node.
However, sometimes a node is only < root node and neither < or > than another node.

Any ideas, hints or the like would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt you can minimize *children count of* **ANY** *node* while talking about the *entire* tree. That doesn't sound like a correct question.

Comment: A root node pointing at two linked lists?

Comment: Jens, could you tell us a little about *why* you want to do this?

Comment: "The children count of any node is minimized" - solution is a single linked list, not sure why would you still call it a "tree".

Comment: @Gareth The rough description of the idea behind this problem is: How can I nest a given amount of hollow 3D objects while limiting the space used by the outer cubes.

Comment: @AlexeiPolkhanov A single linked list is not really feasible due to the conditions (the order) given. I cannot guarantee that a node is < than any other node than the root node.

Comment: The one @Gareth should have been "used by the outer objects or cuboids" at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it sounds as if you just want to: (1) sort the nodes into descending order, then (2) make each node a child of its predecessor if its value is strictly smaller than the predecessor's, and a sibling of its predecessor otherwise. This way, the height of the tree is simply the number of distinct values, which is the biggest it can possibly be given your third condition.

I can't help suspecting that you're wanting something more complicated. Am I missing the point somehow?

Comment: This was my reaction as well.

Comment: Possibly there is some subtlety about "The children count of any node is minimized"? You can't increase the depth more than this, nor change the average number of children per node - but you can reduce the maximum number of children per node at the cost of tree height.

Comment: I believe the answer is as simple as this. In the end, it boils down to inserting each node into the tree while obeying the given conditions. Even a maximum children count of, e.g., 2 per node should be easily implementable using this I guess.
I'll implement this tomorrow and reply / accept depending on my results. Thanks for the reply though, I guess I was thinking too complex the whole time :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alexei, I think what you want to do is a linked list with a custom insertion function that inserts the elements in a specific order.
This was based on your question.

Now, I don't now what exactly you are trying to do here, but if the goal is to keep an efficient sorted collection of objects, my guess would be to use a [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).
Traversing this tree in order will be very easy and return a sorted list of items. Insertions and deletions are pretty easy too and only have an average complexity of O(log n).